# Why doesn’t runway 31R at JFK have a VGSI?

Tags: runways, airport-lighting, kjfk

All of the runways at JFK have a PAPI except 31R.

[image]

Why does 31R not have any kind of VGSI?

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24358/what-determines-the-positioning-of-papi-lights-from-the-runway-threshold).  PAPI's are usually placed at the touchdown point for the runway.  By looking at this satellite photo you can see that the touchdown point is at the intersection of 31R and 22R-04L so there is no room for the PAPI.

[image]

Comment: The PAPI's for all the other runways are placed just short of the 1500 foot marker. The same placement here would put them past 22R. There must be some other reason

Comment: @TomMcW:  You appear to be correct about the placement of the other PAPIs.  They must make allowances for eye-to-wheel height of some larger airplanes.  In that case there appears to be a runway hold sign at the location where the PAPI would be.  Perhaps that is the reason.

Comment: If you want to, you’ll find a place to mount it. I know a small airport where it’s in front of the RWY threshold mounted on top of street lights of an adjacent street, then you just have to fly the last 50m without glidescope indicator – there is always a possibility to put it somewhere.